# Is it possible to save GeoJSON with indent by QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geojson, indentation

If I have GeoJSON layer in QGIS and once it is saved, all indent structure is missing.
This is not friendly to work with git.

Is it possible to save GeoJSON with indent by QGIS?

Comment: Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or [`python json.tool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json.tool) in a [git pre-commit hook](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks)?